# Matching just the root/home page in Tampermonkey / Greasemonkey?

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I want to only match this specific link `https://google.com/` and I don't want it to match anything else.

I tried:

```
// @match       *https://google.com/*
```

For example, I don't want it to match something like `https://google.com/images`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [the Match Patterns documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Just use:

```
// @match    https://google.com
```